# Shell script popup with sound

Tags: bash, shell-scripting

I have a shell script running in crontab to perform certain checks. In case of any problem I want to alert user. For that purpose I am using zenity and play command

```
zenity --error --text='Something has happened!' --display=:0.0   // for pop up
play /somepath/somefile.wav                                      // for sound
```

These two are working fine independently. **But I want to `play` the alarm until `zenity` error is acknowledged.** After searching in internet I found zenity does not have audio alarm inbuilt support. I want to know how to achieve my goal. Any other solution is also ok if it is not a third party solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a proper monitoring solution?

Comment: What solutions are you referring?

Comment: one of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems

Comment: Actually script looks for some configuration files required for an in house developed software

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
zenity --error --text='Something has happened!' --display=:0.0 &
while [ -d /proc/$! ];do play /somepath/somefile.wav;done
```

Comment: This could do with some explanation. Also it won't work without `&`. Finally this is highly dependent on how the shell implements its `wait` calls. So I'd worry if a minor implementation change of the shell in the future would cause it to stop working. You are not explicitly calling `wait` you are relying on the shell doing it implicitly. If the shell didn't do that you'd be looping forever waiting for a zombie to go away, meanwhile the zombie will stay around until the parent `wait`s or terminates.

Comment: It worked for me. @kasperd can you provide some elegant solution?